# ngx-graph custom template of node

Tags: angular, ngx-graph

How can I change The initial node template which is made by an svg to a custom html  template with all html elemnts.
basically i want to do alike graph of this
without hurting the package functionalities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use HTML instead of SVG, you can use the `foreignObject` SVG element and embed your HTML inside of it:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject

Example:

```
  <ng-template #nodeTemplate let-node>
    <svg:foreignObject>
      <div>Your HTML here</div>
    </svg:foreignObject>
  </ng-template>
```